# how to convert the json file into excel using node.js considering twitter data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

```js
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
    
json2csv({data: someJSONData, fields: ['screen_name', 'statuses_count', 'location']}, function(err,csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log(csv);
});
var json = [
  {
    "screen_name: "Doug_E_Stile"",
    "statuses_count": 1546,
    "location": "Maryland""
  }, {
    "screen_name": "cthxidm",,
    "statuses_count": 339,
    "location": "peru manyasÂ¿",
  }, {
    "screen_name": ""jiiiiimarjoh",
    "statuses_count":  4205,,
    "location": "South Cotabato, Philippines"
  }
];
json2csv({data: json, fields: ['screen_name', 'statuses_count', 'location']}, function(err, excel) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });
});
```

i wrote the code to convert the json into the csv but it not working me can anybody help me .it will be great help[ for me

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a variable named `csv`, but the name of your function parameter is `excel`. It should be:

```
fs.writeFile('file.csv', excel, function(err) {
```

instead of

```
fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
```

Comment: thank you but still i am getting error  saying that  file not linked

Comment: i save this file as fromat.js but not linking in my app.js how i do it ... can give me idea